# Combining conditions to check if mobile or if window was resized

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to run some javascript if the device is a desktop computer or if the window width is above 600px. If these conditions aren't met, then I try to check if the device is a mobile or if the window width is less than 600px to run some different code for mobile devices.

Checking if it is a mobile device does work and the alert is displayed, but resizing the window does not.

```
var winWidth = $(window).width();

// Checking for mobile devices
var isMobile = false;

if (/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ||
    /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(navigator.userAgent.substr(0, 4)))

    isMobile = true;

// Checking if window was resized

var isResized = false;

function resized() {

    $(window).resize(function() {

        // if the width is less than 600 then we set isResized to true

        if ($(window).width() < 600) {

            isResized = true;

        }
    });
}


$(document).ready(function() {

    if (!isMobile ||
        winWidth > 600) {

        // code here

    }

    // if device is a mobile or isResized is true
    else if (isMobile || isResized) {

        alert('resized');

    };

});
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I guess it's not because the function is not called and more over you have alerted only at the document.ready which will be executed only at the start not everytime.

Answer (score 2):

Try this codes as below, Changes it's `background` on `resizing window size` you can even add alert and try.

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/16r1Lwsh/

```js
$(window).on("resize",function(){

 if($(this).width() <= 600){
   $("div").css("background","#111");
 }
 if($(this).width() >= 600){
   $("div").css("background","#f22");
 }
 
});
```

```css
div{
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  background:#f22;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem is with this

```
    function resized() {
  $(window).resize(function() {
    // if the width is less than 600 then we set isResized to true
    if ($(window).width() < 600) {
      isResized = true;
    }
  });
}
```

You have put it inside a function but your objective is to get the value of `isResized`. Also I am not able to see how you are calling this `resized` function.

Instead of putting inside a function you can simply put the code like

```
 $(window).resize(function() {
        // if the width is less than 600 then we set isResized to true
        if ($(window).width() < 600) {
          isResized = true;
        }
      });
```

So on every resizing it will keep on updating the value of `isResized`